# Prove $c\vec{v}+d\vec{w}$ with $c+d\leq 1$ and $c,d\in[0,1]$ represent points inside the triangle formed by the given vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, vectors

> Prove that for two vectors $\vec{v},\vec{w}\in\mathbb{R}^2$, the combinations $\vec{r}=c\vec{v}+d\vec{w}$ with $c+d\leq 1$ and $c,d\in[0,1]$ represent points inside(or on the) the triangle formed by the given vectors.

Let $\vec{v},\vec{w}$ represent point A and B, respectively.

[image: pic]

When $c+d=1$
$$
\vec{r}=c\vec{v}+d\vec{w}=\vec{v}+d(\vec{w}-\vec{v})
$$
is the line passing through A and B. And with the conditions $c,d\in[0,1]$, $\vec{r}=c\vec{v}+d\vec{w}$ represents the line segment AB.

Since inequality of vectors are not defined how do I prove with the condition $c+d<1$ the linear combination $\vec{r}=c\vec{v}+d\vec{w}$ represents points inside the triangle $\Delta OAB$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It become clear if we look at the points instead of vectors. So, $\vec v=A-O=A$ and $\vec w=B-O=B$. A point $P$ in the segment $OD$ can be writen as,

$$P=\alpha D + (1-\alpha)O=\alpha \vec r.$$

with $\alpha \in[0,1]$. At the same time,

$$\vec{AD}=D-A= \vec r - \vec v\to \vec r=\vec{AD}+\vec v$$

but also,

$$\vec{AD}=\beta \vec{AB}=\beta B-\beta A=\beta\vec w-\beta\vec v.$$

with $\beta \in [0,1]$. Finally,

$$P=\alpha \vec r=\alpha(\beta\vec w-\beta\vec v+\vec v)=[\alpha (1-\beta)]\vec v+(\alpha \beta) \vec w= c\vec v+d\vec w.$$

Furthermore, $c+d=\alpha\in[0,1]$ and $c,d\in[0,1]$.

Comment: Or can I simply say, $\vec{p}=c\vec{v}+d\vec{w}$ with $c+d=1$ and $c,d\in[0,1]$ represent the position vectors of the line segment $AB$. Position vectors corresponding to points on or inside $\Delta OAB$, $\vec{r}=\alpha\vec{p}=\alpha c\vec{v}+\beta d\vec{w}=\lambda\vec{v}+\mu\vec{w}$ with $\alpha\in[0,1]$ where $\lambda+\mu=\alpha(c+d)\leq 1$ and $\lambda,\mu\in[0,1]$, right ?

Comment: @ss1729. Yes! I used points instead of vector because I think it is better for undestanding, but you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Let $e = c+d$ and $f = \frac c e$. Then $0 \le e \le 1$ and $0 \le f \le 1$ and

$c \vec v + d \vec w = ef \vec v + e(1-f) \vec w$

So $c \vec v + d \vec w$ lies on the line segmemt between $e \vec v$ and $e \vec w$, and so it is on or on the border of the triangle formed by the origin, $\vec v$ and $\vec w$.